# How to retrieve global_brand_page_name using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to retrieve the global_brand_page_name using Graph API. Here's how my request looks like.

https://graph.facebook.com/pizzahutcanada/global_brand_page_name/?access_token=myAcccessToken

But what is get is:

`{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /global_brand_page_name",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}`

This works in Graph API explorer but not if I access it directly in the URL.

What did I miss? And are there other ways to check if a page is a Global page?

Comment: I suggested an edit since you were exposing a valid access token in public, never do that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GET method should be:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/pizzahutcanada?fields=global_brand_page_name`

Since global_brand_page_name is a property, not an edge of that page.

Comment: Hi Ian, the solution you gave me is not working on my end. Do I need a token for this?

Comment: Yes, I might have forgotten to append the version number of the API. Did it now, an access token should be provided I  think. I just tested it via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: If it works due my response, please be so kind to "accept" my answer ;)